# Camel CXFRS Client Endpoint - Basic Auth Set-Cookie Header Empty

Tags: java, cookies, apache-camel, cxfrs, cxf-client

at first sorry for my bad english!

**The Situation:**

Im currently play around with Camel (2.17), Blueprint and CXF Rest Client on Jboss Fuse 6.3.
I try to invoke a RESTFUL Webservice (Server) with a CXF-RS Consumer (Client) Endpoint. Authenticate with Basic Auth and try to use the authentication cookies (Set-Cookie) from the response for further requests. 
The rsClient endpoint in Camel is run as plain  HTTP client.

**The Problem:**

Everthing seem to work well and i can invoke the target webservice. The outbound and inbound message from cxf looks very good. The inbound response has the set-cookie-header set and filled. **But** after the CXF endpoint does his work and the route progress futher... the header "Set-Cookie" is missing/empty! I checked it with a log endpoint and even with a camel processor bean. The exchange does not contain the "set-cookie" header anymore.
I tried it also with the camel-http4 endpoint and there the "Set-Cookie" header is correctly maintained.

What do i do wrong in this case?

**My simple camel route looks like:**

```
<route id="_route1">
 <from id="_from1" uri="timer:timerName?repeatCount=1"/>
 <to id="_to1" uri="cxfrs:bean:rsClient"/>
 <to id="_log1" uri="log:com.mycompany.test?showAll=true&amp;multiline=true"/>
</route>
```

**My CXF Rest Client config:**

```
 <cxf:rsClient address="https://mywebservice/rest" id="rsClient"
        loggingFeatureEnabled="true"
        password="pass"
        username="user"
        serviceClass="org.MyInterface">
 </cxf:rsClient>
```

**Working http4 Route:**

```
<route id="_route1">
 <from id="_from1" uri="timer:timerName?repeatCount=1"/>
 <to id="_to1" uri="http4://mywebservice/rest?authMethod=Basic&amp;authUsername=user&amp;authPassword=pass"/>
 <to id="_log1" uri="log:com.mycompany.test?showAll=true&amp;multiline=true"/>
</route>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What version of CXF are you using? Perhaps this issue is causing it: [CXF-6451](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6451)?

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. I use Fuse 6.3 with CXF 3.1.5.